# mapping of data between same server but diffrent databases with same table names

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hi I am stuck here need your advice. I have a server with multiple DB's. 
Now I want to map if the data in one table of 1 db is equal to the data in another db with same table name

can anyone suggest how to do that?? thanks in advancve

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: there's a nice product called SQL Delta that does this for you. think it costs though

Comment: sorry forgot to add i am using sql server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends on what you need to map.
If you just want to know the differences by primary key, I would try a full join on the PK, so it will tell you records that exist on A but not on B and records that exists on B but not on A. Like this:

```
create table DB_A(id int)
create table DB_B(id int)

insert into DB_A values (1)
insert into DB_A values (2)

insert into DB_B values (2)
insert into DB_B values (3)

select DB_A.ID as 'Exists on A but not on B', DB_B.id as  'Exists on B but not on A'
from DB_A full join DB_B on DB_A.id=DB_B.id 
where DB_A.id is null or DB_B.id is null
```

if you need more than that like compare the values of all columns, I suggest you to use a data compare tool. It would not be so strait forward to do it using just SQL

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from db1.table1 t1
full outer join db2.table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.id <> t2.id
or t1.col2 <> t2.col2 or ...
```

Comment: but how will you get the values which are not being mapped, and how will that throw an exception